# Mudar classe do parágrafo conforme retorno Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Depois de sofrer bastante consegui fazer funcionar, mas empaquei em uma coisa:

Quando o usuário clica no botão de enviar o `form`, envia os dados para o php via ajax que retorna um valor ou um texto.

Eu queria apenas mudar a classe do `<p>` conforme o conteúdo desse retorno.

O elemento `p` que recebe o retorno é essa abaixo:

```
<p class="alert alert-primary" id="resultado">Resultado vem aqui</p>
```

E o script que envia e recebe o dado é esse abaixo. Acrescentei o `if` para fazer esse teste do conteúdo que vem no retorno, mas não deu certo.

```
$('#ajax').submit(function() {
var form = $(this);
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(retorno) {
    $('#resultado').html(retorno);
    if ((retorno) == 'Preencha todos os campos'){
        document.getElementById("#resultado").className = "alert alert-success";
    };
});
return false;});
```

É a primeira que vez que consegui fazer o envio via ajax e estou bem feliz com isso. Mas me veio uma dúvida: É uma boa prática colocar uma verificação nesse código aí pra evitar que o usuário envie o formulário vazio?

Comment: Seria melhor usar o [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) retornando um JSON tipo `{"resposta": false, "mensagem": "Preencha todos os campos"}`, e o if vc verifica o valor da chave `resposta`, tipo: `if(!retorno.resposta){...`. No caso de tudo estar ok, vc retorna o JSON com a chave `resposta` igual a `true` e uma mensagem opcional: `{"resposta": true, "mensagem": "Deu tudo certo!"}`.

Comment: Fui ler mais sobre o getJSON e achei interessante. Vou ter que estudar mais sobre jquery porque não consegui adaptar o getJSON ao que fiz aqui. Por exemplo. Depois de enviar, o dado que retorna do php é um objeto php ou um exit('esse texto'). Desse jeito que ta aí funciona legal e retorna certinho. Só esse troço de mudar a cor conforme o que retorna é que ta pegando. Percebi aqui que justamente devido o tipo do retorno, o script não consegue ler o conteúdo. Mas estranho é que pelo menos o texto deveria dar (acho)

Answer (score 0):

use notify.js para modificar a cor da resposta ou alert ou sucesso tem varios tipo de possibilidades com notify.

https://notifyjs.jpillora.com/ <- pode ver se encaixa na tua questão...

exemplo: eu tenho que modificar uma resposta que vem em array json de uma requisição do ajax e supondo que eu precisa que ela tenha uma cor de fundo

```
 <script>$('document').ready(function(){$('#click').click(function(){$.notify("olha como fica", "success");})})</script>
```